# How to remove items from lista comparing with another list listb

Tags: python

I have two lists Lista and Listb ,am trying to update Lista by removing all the elements from it present in Listb,how do I do that?

```
Lista = ['1535408', '1527610', '1532634']
Listb = ['1527610', '1532634']

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
 Lista = ['1535408']
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve duplicate elements?

Comment: `list(set(Lista) - set(Listb))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehensions

```
>>> Lista = ['1535408', '1527610', '1532634']
>>> Listb = ['1527610', '1532634']
>>> Lista = [item for item in Lista if item not in Listb]
['1535408']
```

If you don't want to preserve duplicates elements then:

```
>>> set(Lista).difference(Listb)
{'1535408'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a set from the elements of `Listb` (for the O(1) lookup time). Use a list comprehension and a reassignment to do the filtering.

```
>>> Lista = ['1535408', '1527610', '1532634']
>>> Listb = ['1527610', '1532634']
>>> b_items = set(Listb)
>>> Lista = [item for item in Lista if item not in b_items]
>>> Lista
['1535408']
```